# Hardware Wallet Security if Computer App (MEW, Ledger, Trezor) is compromised

Tags: wallet

I have bought a Ledger and Trezor.

I don't want to use My Ether Wallet, it gets hacked! I just want to go from the exchange to the Trezor. But, I have about 15 ALT COINS and I'm reading and hearing I can't use the Trezor/Ledger for all of them?

Is there a better alternative? How are hardware wallets secured against MEW hacks?

Comment: Could you please edit the title of your question to summarize the main question?

Answer (score 2):

> But, I don't want to use MEW My Ether Wallet, it gets hacked!

The point of a hardware wallet is that even if the software or service you are using is compromised that your private keys are still safe. So even if MEW gets hacked, you can still use it and be sure that your private keys are still secure. The private keys never leave the Trezor or Ledger and in order to send any money anywhere, you need to confirm it on the device so your coins can't be stolen without you being aware of the transaction.